# Visual studio 2013 - not have reference for creating excel file.

Tags: c#, com, reference, visual-studio-2013, xls

I want to create Excel file.
I am using visual studio 2013.
All code example suggest to use 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel \Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library.
But I dont see any dll like those in COM tab ( add reference ->  COM tab).

What is the reason?
How can I add the reference?
 is there another way to create .XLS and write to it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to install microsoft office first. Anyway I would suggest to use EPPlus (just search on codeplex for it)

Comment: They are .NET assebmlies, not COM, and would be in the Framework tab, not the COM tab. Do you have Office installed?  Or at least the [Office Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx)?

Comment: I have Excel viewer of Microsoft, Is it Enough?

Comment: Solved!
I installed the microsoft Excel and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use open xml sdk , to manage the Excel file as XML document. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180830%28v=office.14%29.aspx).